# Rails content_for not rendering partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, partial, content-for

For some reason I can not render a partial inside a `content_for` block.

Here's the code:

```
/ => index.html.slim
doctype html
html lang="de"
  = render "layouts/headinclude"
  body
    = yield
    - if Rails.env.production?
      - content_for :additional_headincludes do
        = render "layouts/hotjar"
```

For some reason the following does not include my partial once fully rendered:

```
  / # => _headinclude.html.slim
  head
    title= @title || "My Title"
    link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    - if content_for?(:additional_headincludes)
      = yield :additional_headincludes
```

I do not see a reason why this would not work. Any help is appreciated.
When rendering the partial directly inside my `headinclude`-partial, it's working all fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here was with the order.
I had to define the `content_for`-block prior to calling `render "layouts/headinclude"`.

Note that this concept would've worked if the "answering" `content_for`-block (the one containing the `render "layouts/hotjar"`-part) was inside a template (Like `show` or `index` or in whatever template you currently are). Reason for that is the order the content gets resolved by Rails.

A template seems to get resolved before the layout, so in this case the "asking" `content_for`-block would've had actual data to display.

Here's (one possible) an answer:

```
/ => index.html.slim
- if Rails.env.production?
  - content_for :additional_headincludes do
    = render "layouts/hotjar"
doctype html
html lang="de"
  = render "layouts/headinclude"
  body
    = yield
```

I hope this helps somebody.